# Constructor type mismatch in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm self-learning linked list in java and I was writing a basic program. I'm getting errors related to constructors that I cannot understand. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class prac{

public class Linked{

    public void display(Node head)
    {
        if(head==null) // list is empty
        {
            return ;
        }
        Node current=head;
        while(current!=null)
        {   System.out.print(current.data+ " --> ");
            current=current.next;
        }
        System.out.println(current);
    }
    private class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        public Node(int data)
        {
            this.data=data;
            this.next=null;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Node head=new Node(10);
    Node second=new Node(11);
    Node third=new Node(5);
    Node fourth=new Node(1);
    head.next=second;
    second.next=third;
    third.next=fourth;
    Linked linklist=new Linked();
    linklist.display(head);
}
}
```

```
Some of the errors are this:
error: constructor Node in class Node cannot be applied to given types;
    Node fourth=new Node(1);
                ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
    Linked linklist=new Linked();
                    ^
prac.java:40: error: incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to prac.Linked.Node
    linklist.display(head);
```

Can anyone please explain how to solve this error and the reason behind it? I'm stuck here.
/

Comment: `Node` has no constructor that expects an int. Either create or use a different one.

Comment: `Node head=new Node(10);` which class is this ? your own ?

Comment: I don't understand. You have class prac, which has class Linked, which has class Node.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an inner class and you have a variable type as same, then that will take priority

```
  Node current=head;
```

this refers to the private inner class

In your main method

```
 Node head=new Node(10)
```

this refers to a different class

To solve this issue, one option, change the inner class name, other option create a constructor and copy all the values to that object

```
private class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    public Node(mypackage.Node node) {
        this.data = node.data;
        this.next = node.next;
    }

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data=data;
        this.next=null;
    }
}
```

Then change you display function as

```
Node current=new Node(head);
```

In this code `mypackage` is assumed to be your own package or a third party library

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access the `Node`class from higher scope because it is `private` to the `Linked` class. Only within the linked class can you actually create a Node object due to it's access restriction.

In my solution, I initially split the classes, so `Linked` is no longer inside the `Prac` class. Otherwise all of your methods would have to be naturally `static` due to `Prac` having the main method

`public static void main(String[] args)`.

Additionally, I chose to keep the **Node** constructor private, but expose an `addNode(int value)` method publicly which you can call.

The solution is [here](https://repl.it/repls/IdioticClearAnimatronics) to help.